# Stop form whitespace when user pressing submit

Tags: javascript, php, function, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Okay, so I have a form. Applied a function to it.

All I want to do is when the form is submitted it launches the function, it checks to see if there is white space and throws out a message. I have the following:

```js
function empty() {
  var x;
  x = document.getElementById("Username").value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Please ensure you fill in the form correctly.");
  };
}
```

```html
<input type='submit' value='Register' onClick='return empty()' />
<input type='text' id="Username" />
```

This is fine for if someone pressed the space-bar once and enters one line of whitespace, but how do I edit the function so that no matter how many spaces of whitespace are entered with the space-bar it will always throw back the alert.

Thanks in advance. I am very new to JavaScript. So please be gentle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactely but you might be thinking of .trim()

Answer (score 5):

Trim the string before testing it.

```
x = document.getElementById("Username").value.trim();
```

This will remove any whitespace at the beginning and end of the value.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a function for the same, i added another checks (including a regular expresion to detect multiples empty spaces). So here is the code:

```
function checkEmpty(field){
    if (field == "" ||
        field == null ||
        field == "undefinied"){

        return false;
    }
    else if(/^\s*$/.test(field)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is an example working with jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/p87qeL7f/

Here is the example in pure javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/g7oxmhon/

Note: the function `checkEmpty` still be the same for both

Comment: Are you able to provide this without jQuery framework? As won't work for me.

Comment: Of course, now i have updated the example, the function `checkEmpty` still be the same, i just changed the jquery stuff below :)

Answer (score 0):

```
this work for me   
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Description').bind('input', function() {
            var c = this.selectionStart,
                r = /[^a-z0-9 .]/gi,
                v = $(this).val();
            if (r.test(v)) {
                $(this).val(v.replace(r, ''));
                c--;
            }
            this.setSelectionRange(c, c);
 
        });
       
    });
    
    function checkEmpty(field) { //1Apr2022 new code 
        if (field == "" ||
            field == null ||
            field == "undefinied") {
    
            return false;
        } else if (/^\s*$/.test(field)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```